# iOS: Custom UITableViewCell touch receiver confusion

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

have seen similar questions but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Having mastered regular tables of most types, I am doing some conceptual experiments with custom table cells to get familiar with how this works.  I want to have a custom subclass of UITableViewCell which loads a nib to the contentView.  I may want to implement different editing styles at some later point but want to reuse the custom view in different parts of my application, however, i'm having problem receiving the didSelectRowAtIndexPath message in my calling UITableViewController.

Here's the hierarchy which is built from a basic view template.

CustomCellViewController: A stock XCode objective-c class sublcassed from UITableViewCell

```
@interface CustomCellViewController : UITableViewCell {
  IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;

@end

@implementation CustomCellViewController

@synthesize lbl;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *a = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCellView" owner:self options:nil];
        UITableViewCell *tc = [a objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Cell loaded from nib");
        [self.contentView addSubview:tc];
    }
    return self;
}

.. the other stock methods are unchanged ..

@end
```

I realise that the init method could be simplified but this is my first attempt.

The XIB file's owner is my custom class (CustomCellViewController), has a UITableViewCell and a label (linked to the outlet 'lbl' on it) positioned half way accross, leaving plenty of the underlying UITableViewCell clickable.

RootViewController is a standard, stock XCode subclass of UITableViewController
RootViewController sets up an instance variable "CustomTableCellController *myCustomCell"

The cellForRowAtIndexPath: is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCustomCell";

    CustomCellViewController *cell = (CustomCellViewController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {  
        cell = [[[CustomCellViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        NSLog(@"Creating New cell for position %d", indexPath.row);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Reusing cell for position %d", indexPath.row);
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hi There %d", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

And in the same RootViewController.m, my didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Cell tapped at row %d", indexPath.row);
    /*
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    */
}
```

Designed at present, to purely output a log message when tapped.

numberOfSectionsInTableView returns 1
numberOfRowsInSection returns 50

This all compiles and runs fine, iPhone simulator starts, I see a table on the display, my output log confirms it has created 9 versions of CustomCellViewController and I can see the reuse stack via the NSLog() comments.

I just can't select a row, doesn't matter where I click in the custom cell, nothing gets to my didSelectRowAtIndexPath: in my RootViewController which is where I expect it.

Is it that I have I not set a delegate somewhere and if so, how?  Do I need to do this via a first responder?  (ie, create a method in my CustomCellViewController class, link the UITableViewCell from the XIB to that method and then call [super didSelectRowAtIndexPath] - but how do I pass the indexPath?

Am I not responding to a message from my XIB in it's owner and then passing it on (is this how I do it?)

I read through all the apple docs to get to this stage but couldn't quite decipher how touch messaging happened.

Slightly confused!

Answer (score 1):

May be you have forget to set data source and delegate if the tableview object set it as like below

```
tbl.delegate = self;
tbl.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: also write <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>  at interface line to implement it's method

Comment: Re delegate and datasource, if you're talking about in my RootViewController where the UITableView is initiated from, datasource is correct as the cells get populated and I know delegate is set correctly because if I reverse my cellForRowAtIndexPath code to use the stock UITableViewCell, didSelectRowAtIndex gets called.  In which file are you talking about adding the protocols?  RootViewController or my CustomCellViewController?  Again, even without them implicitly, the RootView ones work if I don't use my custom cell, the cell is not accepting the touch event on behalf of the table.

Comment: In your custom cell there is a label . is you label set the text exactly that you are setting. also try to check after removing the label. may be your label create some problem

Comment: Yes, if I do `cell.lbl.text = @"some text";` it gets there to the label, the label doesn't completely occlude the table cell object below it, it's as if something's not completely wired up to pass the click down to a receiver but I can't connect anything in IB to a method within my custom table cell class

Comment: Additionally, all the other examples seem to load the nib in the cellForRowAtIndexPath but require a class file as well but I can't seem to understand how the NIB then knows about the functions in the class (argghhhh!) is it something to do with my NIB effectively replacing the cell and maybe doesn't have a `contentView` property at that stage.  Anyone got a URL of a walkthrough which uses a custom class which loads the NIB rather than the TableViewDataSource loading the NIB directly, in otherwords `cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier];`